# jquery serialize not picking up active bootstrap buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code which is set on page load

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                                        <label class="btn btn-default active" for="hrb">
                                            <input type="radio" id="hrb" name="period" value="hourly" /> Hourly
                                        </label> 
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" for="drb">
                                            <input type="radio" id="drb" name="period" value="daily" /> Daily
                                        </label> 
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" for="wrb">
                                            <input type="radio" id="wrb" name="period" value="weekly" /> Weekly
                                        </label> 
                                        <label class="btn btn-default" for="mrb">
                                            <input type="radio" id="mrb" name="period" value="monthly" /> Monthly
                                        </label> 
                                    </div>
```

If I use jquery serialize to get the selected values it returns nothing

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var input = $(".btn-group").find('input');
    console.log(input);

    var data = input.serialize() ; //$( "form" ).serialize();
    console.log(data);
});
```

I managed to do the following, unless someone has a better way of doing it?

```
var group_period = 'period=';
            $('#group_period .active').each(function(){
                group_period += $(this).attr('data-value'); 
            }); 
    var requiredrole = "requiredrole=" + $("requiredrole").val();

    var data = requiredrole + "&" + group_period + "&" + $( "form" ).serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

your example is not working just because you don't have active element on page load, using `checked="checked"` you set a default selected element so your script will work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $(".btn-group input");
  var data = $('input').serialize(); //$( "form" ).serialize();
  $('#result').html(data);
  
  $('.go').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('input').serialize(); //$( "form" ).serialize();
    $('#result').html(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default active" for="hrb">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="hrb" name="period" value="hourly" /> Hourly
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" for="drb">
    <input type="radio" id="drb" name="period" value="daily" /> Daily
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" for="wrb">
    <input type="radio" id="wrb" name="period" value="weekly" /> Weekly
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" for="mrb">
    <input type="radio" id="mrb" name="period" value="monthly" /> Monthly
  </label>
  <button class="go">
  SERIALIZE
  </button>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: how do i make it run after page laod then?

Comment: using a button ( or something that fire an event ) or define a default value.... you can also listen to the change event of the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use name field value as an array like period[] instead of period.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default active" for="hrb">
        <input type="radio" id="hrb" name="period[]" value="hourly" /> Hourly
    </label> 
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="drb">
        <input type="radio" id="drb" name="period[]" value="daily" /> Daily
    </label> 
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="wrb">
        <input type="radio" id="wrb" name="period[]" value="weekly" /> Weekly
    </label> 
    <label class="btn btn-default" for="mrb">
        <input type="radio" id="mrb" name="period[]" value="monthly" /> Monthly
    </label> 
</div>
```

Comment: I only want to be able to select one radio and not multiple?

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to be working except could it be that you're trying to receive the serialized value whenever the form updates even though the `input.serialize()` is only fired once at the start?

Try binding:

```
var data = input.serialize() ; //$( "form" ).serialize();
console.log(data);
```

to an event such as `.change()` or perhaps `.click()` bound directly to the button elements.
[.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/),
[.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

---

For reference, I tried your code with a manual updater:

```
$('.btn_test').click(function(){
    var data = input.serialize() ; //$( "form" ).serialize();
    console.log(data);
});
```

and put this directly below the button group:

```
<button class="btn_test">Click</button
```

Obviously this is not what you want, but proves that your input serialization works just fine.
(Output was `period=weekly` in the console log upon clicking `btn_test`)

**Edit**: Damn, @Vanojx1 beat me to it.